# How to locate second image which contain specific text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

The website has standard image which i can use to identify the xpath.
but i want to click on the third image which contains specific text only.
the picture is beside the image, it that fine to have img and text in one command line?

- Original working code:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//img[@class='s-image'])[2]")).click();
  ```
- Try to insert the contains command but it does not work:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//img[@class='s-image'])[2] and contains(text(),'Apple MacBook Pro')")).click();
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have tried wrong option that is not text that is alt property to get into xpath.Try now.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//img[@class='s-image'][contains(@alt,'Apple MacBook Pro')])[2]").click()
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//img[@class='s-image'][starts-with(@alt,'Apple MacBook Pro')])[2]").click()
```

Comment: above is the link for clear picture. how to click on the second image in the list?

Comment: @user2201789 : Edited the answer.Check now.You have to select alt property of image.there is no text attribute of image tag.

Comment: Sorry provided you python code but xpath remain same in Java as well just use the xpath not the entire code. My mistake.I’ll update it later or you can edit I am away now can’t change ATM.

Comment: i trying to modify to java. but able to. not sure what else missing